# How to design database schema to store multiple value in one column?

Tags: database

I have a database design here: [I want to add a LIST of Products selected by a Customer into purchase table->product column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGXX7.jpg)

How should i define the attributes in "localhost/phpmyadmin" so that the column can hold multiple value?[Here say i want to store multiple product id in product_id column. How should i define the schema attributes?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHHNR.jpg)

Comment: provide us the code you tried ? Before we can help you. We are not here to provide this to you if you did not try it by yourself before.

Comment: what code you need for defining the attribute in database table? I just need how to define database schema to store array within one column.